# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: string; }'

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, ngrx

I have a problem with argument in dispatch =>
Error: "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: string; }'."

```
export class CharacterDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
 id: string | null= '';
 characterDetail$!: Observable<DataFromAPI>;

 constructor(
   private router: ActivatedRoute,
   private store$: Store
 ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.id = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
   this.getCharacterDetail();
 }

 getCharacterDetail() {
   if (!this.id) {
     return;
   }
   this.store$.dispatch(getCharDetailData(this.id));
   this.characterDetail$ = this.store$.select(charDetailsSelector);
 }
```

}

So who know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```js
   this.store$.dispatch(getCharDetailData({id: this.id}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can You change your **id: string | null= ''**  to **id: any | null= '';**
or
You can set your dataType string where you want to dispatch.